# How can i put the value from observer/event into a dropdown

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

I have a dropdown menu, How can i put the value from observer or event to a dropdown on checkout page. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link:
[How i can add the custom dropdown at the checkout page](https://community.magento.com/t5/Building-Extensions/How-i-can-add-the-custom-dropdown-at-checkout-page/m-p/452190#M1071)

And add your option value into 'options'

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['drop_down'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
            'id' => 'drop-down',
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.drop_down',
        'label' => 'Drop Down',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 251,
        'id' => 'drop-down',
        'options' => [
            [
                'value' => '',
                'label' => 'Please Select',
            ],
            [
                'value' => '1',
                'label' => 'First Option',
            ]
        ]
    ];
```